# How would you translate the exclamation, "How morbid!"

Tags: vocabulary, adjective, gender

I would like to exclaim in Latin, "how morbid!" This came up because just recently I read something morbid. But how would I say this? I am guessing that this is possible:

> Quam morbidus!

But when I made this guess, I wasn't sure which gender to assign the adjective. Is there a rule about which gender to assign the adjective in simple exclamations like these?

I have thought about this question a bit, and I think it might depend on the referent. If the implication is, "How morbid (you are)!" then it makes sense to assign the gender of the person being referred to. But if the implication is "How morbid (that is)!" then perhaps it should be neuter.

Look forward to hearing your thoughts. Also, if "morbidus" is not the best adjective to use, feel free to suggest a better one.

Comment: Interestingly, I couldn't find any words at all to describe the modern definitions morbid, unless one substituted it with obscene, gross, or creepy.

Comment: I'd go for the gender of an underlying noun: _quam horrida [scripta]_

Comment: @Rafael That seems safe. But I would also be interested to know if there is an established expression for this in classical Latin. It's something we say frequently in English, so I wonder if the Romans ever expressed the thought.

Comment: The closest exclamation in classical sources that I found with a quick search was Seneca, De Ira, 3.28.1: *O quam bonum tempus in re mala perdis!* I expected to find something in Plautus, but after five plays there is no sign of *quam* exclamations.

Comment: On the lines of _agis quam pessime_ (you couldn't do worse), _vale quam optime!_ (all the best to you!), why not _quam morbose_ ?

Comment: @TomCotton I like *quam morbose*. Is there an implied verb in there, e.g., *quam morbose (dicis)*?

Comment: @ktm5124 A verb here is no more necessary than in English, but adding _dicis_ is fine.

Comment: The problem is that most people are using *morbid* incorrectly. It isn't synonymous with macabre, grotesque, gross, obscene, etc. It means "unhealthy." A *morbid sense of humor* is just another way of saying a *sick sense of humor*. And it's productive in this sense, too, as we saw during COVID when everyone was talking about *co-* ***morbid*** *ities*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A possible construction (I think more likely than *quam*) would be the accusative of exclamation ([Allen and Greenough 397d](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/allen-greenough/Chapters/Chapter-397.html)):

> O morbidum!

This is assuming a neuter (or masculine) referent. But you could add a specific noun, e.g. *O morbidam fabulam* "What a morbid story!"

Probably there are better choices than *morbidus*, which L&S [call](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dmorbidus) "rare and only ante-class. and post-Aug.", but I'm not sure what they are (especially without more context).

Comment: Thanks! Great to learn about the accusative of exclamation.

Comment: @ktm5124 We have the same in English, too. It's "O poor me!" and not "O poor I!"